# if(ModelState.IsValid) doesn't work with FormsCollection. What to use instead?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation

To validate a HttpPost action that's bound to a concrete type, I can use ModelState.IsValid

```
    public ActionResult Create(MyModelType myModel)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do some stuff
            return RedirectToAction("Details", 0);
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

This obviously won't work with a `FormCollection`, because there is no model to validate

```
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid) // Never invalid
        {
```

What should one use instead of `ModelState.IsValid` when the action accepts a `FormCollection`?

*P.S. A thousand apologies, I **know** this is a dumb question*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal. You need `UpdateModel`:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new MyModelType();
    UpdateModel(model);
    if(ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In the first case the default model binder is invoked because it needs to bind your model from the request. This default model binder will then based on your Data Annotation rules perform the validation. In the second case you do nothing. The controller action has no knowledge of your model and its data annotations for validation. So the model state will always be valid as there is nothing that would make it invalid.

This being said, you should always use the first approach. `FormCollection` is just useless. Even if you go with the second approach (which I totally wouldn't recommend) as you can see you don't need any FormCollection.

Comment: Thanks for that mate. The problem I'm trying to overcome is . . . My first Asp Mvc app (which is also my first - from scratch - Web App) is an in-house proof of concept that requires a dynamic forms to be created at run time. UpdateModel is a generic method, and I won't know the model type at compile time. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Binary Worrier, because validation is defined on your model you need a model. If you have some dynamic forms then you will have to do validation manually. Like read the request value (which of course will be a string), parse it to the corresponding type, verify if it is valid and if it is not add model error, etc ... There is no magic here.

Comment: That's the way I'll go then, thanks for all your help mate . . . P.S. I've been looking at Asp Mvc for approx 20 hours or so, I'm still at the stage where it **all** looks like magic :) That I _have to_ do all validation manually will actually simplify things. Thanks again mate.

Comment: I just have dynamic form requirement and custom `ModelMetadataProvider` and `ModelValidatorProvider` seems like promising. In my case, I define the metadata and validation dynamically in db. [Customizing ASP NET MVC 2 Metadata and Validation](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Customizing-ASP-NET-MVC-2-Metadata-and-Validation.aspx). I think it should be valid at least until MVC4.

Answer (score 0):

And if you manually populate your model, using the `FormCollection`, ensure that you trigger model validation explicitly. You can use the `TryValidateModel` method for this purpose:

Example:

```
var model = new YourModelType {
    Firstname = FormCollection[nameof(YourModelType.FirstName)]
};
TryValidateModel(model);
if(!ModelState.IsValid) {
 // ... error
}
```